# Clearing app data before deactivating the account

Tags: android, sql, database

I need to simulate Settings -> Clear Data function in my application in just before to deactivate the user account. To do this I use the following code;

```
            private boolean clearCacheData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            boolean result = true;
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    result &= deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Log.i("TAG",
                            "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/"
                                    + s + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

When I do that, I also open my welcome page again in order to give the user a change to reactivate the account. If the user continue to reactivate my app crashes and gives `Sq-lite` Disk I/O Error. But if user kills the app and then reopen it, everything's just work expected. What might be the problem?

Do I forgot to close something?

Comment: It seems like while your code is busy deleting the directories and the user registers again you are trying to recreate the directories.

I will suggest to synchronize the read/write of data to the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you have forgotten to close either an `SQLiteDatabase` or a `Cursor` somewhere in your code. Make sure that you do this before you delete your databases as any future to these will raise an SQLite Disk I/O Error exception.